# JavaScript Calculation Problem - NaN message

Tags: javascript, nan

I'm calculating a total number. I get the sum values from div's. But in total, instead of numbers I get (NaN - Not a Number)

JavaScript Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function calculateTotal(){
                var total = document.getElementById('valor1').innerHTML*1 + document.getElementById('valor2').innerHTML*1 + document.getElementById('valor3').innerHTML*1 + document.getElementById('valor4').innerHTML*1 + document.getElementById('valor5').innerHTML*1 + document.getElementById('valor6').innerHTML*1;
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
            }
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

I found the error, I had a closing tag inside the DIV's like this:

```
<center><div id="valor1"></center></div>
```

Changed to:

```
<center><div id="valor1"></div></center>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="valor1">2</div>
<div id="valor2">2</div>
<div id="valor3">ccccc</div>
<div id="valor4">2</div>
<div id="valor5">2</div>
<div id="valor6">2</div>
<hr/>
<div id="total">0</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
function get(elem) { return parseFloat($(elem).innerHTML) || 0; }

(function() {
    var total =
        get('valor1') * 1 + get('valor2') * 1 + get('valor3') * 1 + 
        get('valor4') * 1 + get('valor5') * 1 + get('valor6') * 1;
    $('total').innerHTML = total;
}());
```

A little optimization of the work and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NFUcP/).

But why stop here? :) we can make it even better ( I think ):

```
function get(elem) {
    return (parseFloat($(elem).innerHTML) || (function() {
        $(elem).innerHTML += " <i>Not a number assumed 0</i>";
        return 0;
    }()));
}
```

And the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NFUcP/2/).

Edit: no errors on Chrome & Mozilla (Linux).

Comment: Apreciate for your answer, nice one :)

Comment: It worked for Mozilla, but in IE8 not :S instead of Total it shows only 0

Comment: @Rafael Santos I`m on Linux, don`t have that one :( to test it

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use document.getElementById('valor1').innerHTML directly. You have to convert this to number. Please try this.

```
var value = document.getElementById('valor1').innerHTML;
var number = parseFloat(value)||0;
```

Do this for each div innerHTML which have number.

```
var number = parseFloat(value)||0;
```

The above line will help you to assign 0 to value if div is empty or div html cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: Sometimes blank doesn't mean 0 - it's null or unasigned. +1 for a beautiful option though!

Answer (score 4):

Use `parseFloat(document.getElementById('x').innerHTML)` to convert them to numbers before performing operations:

```
var total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x1').innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById('x2').innerHTML);
```

You also may want to check them if they're numeric, here's a simple test using `isNaN`:

```
alert((isNaN("23"))?'not number':'number');
```

Comment: @Rafael - Hm... If parseFloat doesnt work, I think innerHTML of your element is not really a number... Check them...

Comment: @Rafael - Have you tried @MAK's answer? try it, I think it will work.

Comment: Yes, some of my divs are empty.

Answer (score 1):

try using parseInt() as in

```
var total = parseInt(document.getElementById('valor1').innerHTML)*1 + parseInt(document.getElementById('valor2').innerHTML)*1 + ... ;
```

etc etc

this will ensure that what you're getting out of the fields is in fact, a number

Comment: even better... use parseFloat() - silly of me to assume you'd be using whole numbers

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put these parts into brackets?

```
(document.getElementById('valor1').innerHTML * 1) + ...
```

See: http://rx4ajax-jscore.com/ecmacore/operator/predence.html

Even better - use the parseInt(var string) function;

```
parseInt(document.getElementById('valor1').innerHTML) + ...
```

Comment: (-1) .innerHTML is a string, regardless of the precedence, he will still get NaN.

Comment: but won't `(document.getElementById('valor1').innerHTML * 1)` result in an integer??

Comment: I try, but still shoes the NaN instead of number

Comment: Maybe some `innerHTML` is empty? So `emtyString * 1 == NaN`